# Disable app's menu buttons

Tags: macos

I'd like to disable the default red - yellow - green buttons and the whole menu row in an OS X app. Is it possible? How? Ie. my app would consist of a window where the only content would be the app content (no chrome)

Comment: Please search so I don't have to.

Comment: Not a duplicate. The answer is similar but not similar enough.

Comment: How is it not a duplicate when it leads you to `LSUIElement`?  The answer you've accepted does nothing to the app's menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply uncheck the "Title Bar" box in your window's attribute inspector (Interface Builder) to get a borderless window.

Alternatively you can set the window stylemask in code:

```
[self.window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
//Optional. This makes the window movable by dragging it's content view
[self.window setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
```